# how to find out about transaction state when using asyncpg context manager

Tags: redis, transactions, asyncpg

The script uses 2 redis transactions over asyncpg. I need to catch whether the asyncpg transaction was successful or not in order to confirm or reset the redis transaction

```
        async with cls.sem:
            async with cls.redis_connect.pipeline() as pipe:
                async with cls.pool.acquire() as connection:
                    async with connection.transaction():
```

advice or link to resolve the issue